# .net mvc with class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a project (web) that uses EF. the project works fine i can add, retrieve, update. i have decided to use a class library. i am trying to retrieve a list of (let's say) movies but it doesn't work, gives some error about the models. 
what i did : 
created a class in the library class, added a method into it that returns a list of movies 
 **Library Class**

```
public static class LibMethods
{
    public static List<Movie> get_movies(Entities MovieEntity) //Model in Library Class
    {
        List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();

        var get_movies = from m in MovieEntity.Movie
                          select m;

        if (get_movies.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in get_movies)
            {
                movies.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return movies;
    }
}
```

**Controller Class (MVC)**

```
List<WebAppWithEF.Models.Movie> listMovies = LibMethods.get_movies(new WebAppWithEF.Models.MovieEntities()); //Model in Web Project
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't go through causing an error about an invalid argument. even when i remove the argument it says it can't implicitally convert Library Class Model Movie to the WebApp Model Movie 

**Update** 
I had 2 generated Models (one in webApp & one in the library class) apparently they can't work together therefore i tried deleting the model from the library 1st (but i needed to use ef models inside the lib) therefore i switched and made left the ef models in the lib project & use the lib project connection string (of the EF generated DB) & placed that connection string in the web.config of my webApp

Comment: if i use the method with param it recieves a wrong parameter even thought i pass the entity i generated in the webApp.

Comment: if i use the method without param it says it's can't implicitally convert Library Model Movie to WebApp Model Movie

Comment: fyi: just return `get_movies.ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that MovieEntity.Movie and Movie (from WebApp) models have the same name, but aren't type equivalent. You need to copy the data from MovieEntity.Movie to Movie either using something like AutoMapper or you could just manually copy the properties, either in your method or in the constructor of your model object e.g:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Movie(MovieEntities.Movie movie)
    {
        this.Title = movie.Title;
    }
}
```

More importantly though you need to not pass in a new instance of MovieEntity each time or you'll leak connections in EF.

Comment: I have generated both of Models the same way i just changed the entity name & this is the message it gives that i can't fix `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WebAppWithEF.Models.MovieEntities' to 'LibMethods.ForTestEntities'  `

Answer (score 1):

You should update your get_movies().

```
public static class LibMethods
{
    public static List<Movie> get_movies(Entities MovieEntity) //Model in Library Class
    {
       var movies = from m in MovieEntity.Movie
                      select m;
        return movies.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ye i forgot about that one but i still can't use the method i have in the library

Comment: Please make sure that you have same Movie class used at every location. you should be using the one from EF model.